# Как сделать вибрацию при старте приложения?

Tags: java, android

Задача: запустить вибрацию при запуске приложения.
Такой код выдает ошибку :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d("Start", "MainActivity: onStart()");
    vib.vibrate(1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В AndroidManifest.xml дайте разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Дальше всё также, пример:

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(2000);
}
```

Comment: Я нашел ошибку. Она заключалась в том, что переменную Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); я задавал в public class MainActivity, а надо было непосредственно в protected void onStart() Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Отлично, удачи в дальнейшем.